# how to set default value of select_tag in rails? instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this controller with this action:

```
class CandidatesController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :current_or_guest_user

  def show
    # authorize! :read, @user
    @candidate = Candidate.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @candidates = Candidate.all
    if request.path != candidate_path(@candidate)
      redirect_to @candidate, notice: 'moved permanently'
    end
    @comparison = UserComparisonService.new(current_user, @candidate)
    @contact = ContactCandidate.new(candidate_email: @candidate.email)
  end
```

this calls for a partial to render on the show page and passes the @candidate instance variable:

```
 = render 'users/compare', :candidate => @candidate
```

this is the form within the partial:

```
profile-searchbar.text-left
        = form_tag(compare_path, method: 'get', remote: true, id: 'compare_form') do
          = select_tag "v_friend_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@candidates, :id, :full_name, @comparison.v_friend.id), :include_blank => true, :class => "compare-search", :style => "width:100%; margin-left: 3px

 %a.compare_btn{:href => "javascript:void(0)"}
```

---

This select dropdown works with the candidate.All method in the controller, but how do I set the default value of candidates to be just @candidate, so I can take away the dropdown / search and have it only compare for the candidate's whose page it is on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from the [APIdock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag)

```
select_tag "people", options_from_collection_for_select(@people, "id", "name", "1")
```

And the output is:

```
<select id="people" name="people"><option value="1" selected="selected">David</option></select>
```

As you can see, the `id` is passed as the fourth element on `options_from_collection_for_select` so instead of `@comparison.v_friend.id` I think you have to use `@candidate.id`